# pivot_longer two set of columns in R

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, tidyr

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- data.frame(names = c("John", "Peter", "Mary", "Allan", "Anne"),
                 year = 2001:2005,
                 first_class = letters[1:5],
                 second_class = c("NA", "c", "d", "NA", "e"),
                 third_class = c(letters[1:3], "NA", "NA"),
                 first_day = c("one", "two", "NA", "two", "one"),
                 second_day = c("two", "NA", "one", "one", "two"),
                 third_day = c("NA", "one", "two", "NA", "two"))
```

I want to pivot two sets of columns, “first_class:third_class” and “first_day:third_day”.
I have tried the following syntax:

```
df |>
  pivot_longer(cols = first_class:third_class,
               values_to = "my_class",
               names_to = NULL) |>
  pivot_longer(cols = first_day:third_day,
               values_to = "my_day",
               names_to = NULL)
```

However, the output repeats the same information three times:

```
# A tibble: 45 × 4
   names  year my_class my_day
   <chr> <int> <chr>    <chr> 
 1 John   2001 a        one   
 2 John   2001 a        two   
 3 John   2001 a        NA    
 4 John   2001 NA       one   
 5 John   2001 NA       two   
 6 John   2001 NA       NA    
 7 John   2001 a        one   
 8 John   2001 a        two   
 9 John   2001 a        NA    
10 Peter  2002 b        two
```

The expected result should be as follows:

```
  names year my_class my_day
1  John 2001        a    one
2  John 2001       NA    two
3  John 2001        a     NA
4 Peter 2002        b    two
5 Peter 2002        c     NA
6 Peter 2002        b    one
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
  df %>% 
      pivot_longer(3:8,
               names_to = c("Schedule", ".value"),
               names_sep = "_")
```

By using `.value` you are generating dynamically new columns with the second part of your column names (after the underscore) and you pivot longer the first part assigning it to the variable `Schedule`.

```
names  year Schedule class day  
<chr> <int> <chr>    <chr> <chr>
John   2001 first    a     one  
John   2001 second   NA    two  
John   2001 third    a     NA   
Peter  2002 first    b     two  
Peter  2002 second   c     NA   
Peter  2002 third    b     one  
Mary   2003 first    c     NA
```